# XML and PHP loops

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code in a PHP file while creates data in an XML file;

```
//Check if a file exists
if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
    //Define Variable
    $filename = date('Y-W').'.xml'; //2014-26.xml
    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $xml->load($filename);



    $SequenceType = $xml->getElementsByTagName('SeqTp');
    foreach ($SequenceType as $Type) {
    if ($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'RCUR' AND $Type->nodeValue == 'RCUR') {
    RCUR($filename);
    $RCURExists == 1;
    }
    elseif ($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'FRST'  AND $Type->nodeValue == 'FRST') {
    FRST($filename);
    $FRSTExists == 1;
    }
    elseif ($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'FNAL'  AND $Type->nodeValue == 'FNAL') {
    FNAL($filename);
    $FNALExists == 1;
    }
    elseif ($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'OOFF'  AND $Type->nodeValue == 'OOFF') {
    OOFF($filename);
    $OOFFExists == 1;
    }
    }


    if ($OOFFExists != 1)  
    {
    // call xml appendFile function
        appendFile($filename);
    }
    elseif ($RCURExists != 1) 
    {
    // call xml appendFile function
        appendFile($filename);
        }
    elseif  ($FRSTExists != 1){
    // call xml appendFile function
        appendFile($filename);
    }
    elseif ($FNALExists != 1)
    {
    // call xml appendFile function
        appendFile($filename);
    }
    }
else 
    {
    // call xml createFile function
    createFile($filename);
    }
```

The code is checking the XML file to check if a particular sequence type (e.g. RECUR) has already been included in the file. But lets say the Sequence Type "RECUR" is listed first in the XML file and further down "FRST" is listed. When the code runs, it focuses on the first listed sequence type (RECUR) and `$RECURExists` gets the value 1 (which is what I want) but on the second loop (as there are 2 sequence types in the file) it doesn't get the value one as the condition is not true..any suggestions on how to keep this value?

Example: If 'RCUR' is already included in the XML file, I want to append data to it (which is done by calling the `RCUR($filename)` function. But if 'RCUR' is not already included I want to call the `appendFile($filename)` function.

Comment: Are you thinking something like: `if (($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'RCUR' AND $Type->nodeValue == 'RCUR') OR $RCURExists)`?

Comment: Sorry I actually just solved it after hours of trying and it was so simple...if ($_POST['paymentsequence'] == 'RCUR' AND $Type->nodeValue == 'RCUR') {
 RCUR($filename);
 $RCURExists = $RCURExists + 1;

Comment: Hey @user3266484, it's way cool to post and accept the answer to your own question!

Comment: are you being sarcastic? I didn't know the answer to the question when I posted it. Obviously. I figured if I put up the answer when I found it, it might help someone else.

Comment: I am not being sarcastic. (There's even a badge for it.) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question Please do post your answer below, for the benefit of all.

Comment: Oh haha, sorry I thought you were being sarcastic :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56950/discussion-between-bloodyknuckles-and-user3266484).

Comment: @user3266484: You are really *encouraged* to place your answer below. There is *nothing* wrong with that. Please do so (and no, it's no sarcasm).